# 401 sent to angular frontend by spring boot backend after successful oauth2 authetication with google

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, angular-material

Spring Boot rest api in the back and angular in the front.
Hi all,  I have a problem after successful oauth2 authentication with google.
In srping boot debug I can read the following:
o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor : Skip: response already contains "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".
Then a 401 is sent to angular with full authentication required to access /api/user/ resource which is the root to access user details in the backend side.
WebConfig.java

```
import java.util.Locale;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry
      .addMapping("/**")
      .allowedOrigins("*")
      .allowedMethods(
        "HEAD",
        "OPTIONS",
        "GET",
        "POST",
        "PUT",
        "PATCH",
        "DELETE"
      )
      .maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    final CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return cookieLocaleResolver;
  }

  @Override
  public Validator getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return validator;
  }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.http.converter.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.springboot.dashboard.security.jwt.TokenAuthenticationFilter;
import com.springboot.dashboard.security.oauth2.DashBoardOAuth2UserService;
import com.springboot.dashboard.security.oauth2.DashBoardOidcUserService;
import com.springboot.dashboard.security.oauth2.HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;
import com.springboot.dashboard.security.oauth2.OAuth2AccessTokenResponseConverterWithDefaults;
import com.springboot.dashboard.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import com.springboot.dashboard.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
  prePostEnabled = true,
  securedEnabled = true,
  jsr250Enabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private DashBoardOAuth2UserService dashBoardOAuth2UserService;

  @Autowired
  private DashBoardOidcUserService dashBoardOidcUserService;

  @Autowired
  private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

  @Autowired
  private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
    throws Exception {
    auth
      .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
      .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .cors()
      .and()
      .sessionManagement()
      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
      .and()
      .csrf()
      .disable()
      .formLogin()
      .disable()
      .httpBasic()
      .disable()
      .exceptionHandling()
      .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/", "/error", "/api/all", "/api/auth/**", "/oauth2/**")
      .permitAll()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated()
      .and()
      .oauth2Login()
      .authorizationEndpoint()
      .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
      .and()
      .redirectionEndpoint()
      .and()
      .userInfoEndpoint()
      .oidcUserService(dashBoardOidcUserService)
      .userService(dashBoardOAuth2UserService)
      .and()
      .tokenEndpoint()
      .accessTokenResponseClient(authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient())
      .and()
      .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
      .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);
    // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
    http.addFilterBefore(
      tokenAuthenticationFilter(),
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
    );
  }

  @Bean
  public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
  }

  /*
   * By default, Spring OAuth2 uses
   * HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository to save the authorization
   * request. But, since our service is stateless, we can't save it in the
   * session. We'll save the request in a Base64 encoded cookie instead.
   */
  @Bean
  public HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
    return new HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
  }

  // This bean is load the user specific data when form login is used.
  @Override
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return userDetailsService;
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
  }

  @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  private OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient() {
    OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter = new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseHttpMessageConverter();
    tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter.setTokenResponseConverter(
      new OAuth2AccessTokenResponseConverterWithDefaults()
    );
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
      Arrays.asList(
        new FormHttpMessageConverter(),
        tokenResponseHttpMessageConverter
      )
    );
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new OAuth2ErrorResponseErrorHandler());
    DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient tokenResponseClient = new DefaultAuthorizationCodeTokenResponseClient();
    tokenResponseClient.setRestOperations(restTemplate);
    return tokenResponseClient;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

oauth2 login successful cause user data is successfully to database, but can access to full authentication resource.

Answer (score -1):

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated, don't use it (it is not even there any more in spring-boot 3). Expose a `SecurityFilterChain` bean instead:

```java
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
        // http configuration
        return http.build();
    }
```

## Authorization-server

Unless you deploy your resource-server to Google cloud, it is likely it won't deliver you JWTs. This means that you'll have to use introspection which:

- is hardly acceptable with resource and authorization servers in different data centers (too much latency and network calls)
- requires a "hack" to use user-info endpoint as introspection endpoint because Google OpenID configuration does not expose an introspection endpoint (Google really doesn't want you to use their authorization server for your own resource servers)

For this reasons, you should use an other authorization-server capable of identity federation in front of Google one. Keycloak does it pretty well:

- run a Keycloak instance and configure it with Google as identity provider
- configure your resource-server to use Keycloak as authorization-server (as done in code above)
- configure Angular to use Keycloak as authorization-server too

I refer to Keycloak here, but most serious OIDC providers (either on premize or SaaS like Auth0, Okta, Amazon Cognito, etc.) support "social" login and will allow Google users to login (as well as Facebook, Github, Tweeter, etc.)

## Resource-server (REST API secured with an OAuth2 access token)

Spring has a starter for resource-servers: `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` and I have written my own starters around it to push further the auto-configuration from properties. [Tutorials with both starters here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).

## JS Based Frontend (Angular app)

There are to two different OAuth2 configuration options for JS application running in a browser:

- use a BFF between the JS app and the resource server
- make the JS app an OAuth2 public client

### The BFF pattern

A Backend For Frontend is a middleware on your server configured as an OAuth2 client.

Requests from the front-end to the BFF are secured with sessions (cookies) and request from the BFF to resource servers are secured with access tokens (Bearer Authorization header).

The BFF is responsible for storing tokens in session and replacing the session cookie with the accès token in session before forwarding a request from the browser to REST APIs (resource servers).

Spring Cloud Gateway can be configured as BFF. [Complete tutorial on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).

### JS Application Configured as OAuth2 Public Client

Use an OAuth2 client library use an OAuth2 client library for that. My favorite for Angular is [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client). It will save you tones of efforts to:

- redirect users to authorisation-server for login
- handle redirect back from authorization-server with authorization-code
- exchange authorization-code for tokens (access-token of course, but also refresh and ID tokens if you requested `offline_access` and `openid` scopes)
- auto-refresh access tokens before it expires (if you got a refresh-token)
- automatically authorize request matching configured patterns (add `Authorization` Bearer header with access-token)
- provide with Angular route guards
- ...